# Simulate touch, hold, move in android debug bridge

Tags: android, androidviewclient, adb

Rather than using a `drag` or `swipe` command in the android debug bridge or AndroidViewClient like this:

```
device.drag((600,800),(600,1200), 1000) 
device.shell('input touchscreen swipe 600 800 600 1200 1000')
```

Is there some way to simulate something like the following?

```
1. press down on some coordinates (eventType=DOWN)
2. sleep 2 seconds (i.e. keep holding there)
3. move to some other coordinates
2. sleep 2 seconds (i.e. keep holding there)
5. release (eventType=UP)
```

Basically, you touch, hold there for a few seconds, drag and keep holding there for a few seconds, then release the pad.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at `AdbClient.longPress()` you will see how the long press event is sent for some keys:

```
    if name in KEY_MAP:
        self.shell('sendevent %s 1 %d 1' % (dev, KEY_MAP[name]))
        self.shell('sendevent %s 0 0 0' % dev)
        time.sleep(duration)
        self.shell('sendevent %s 1 %d 0' % (dev, KEY_MAP[name]))
        self.shell('sendevent %s 0 0 0' % dev)
```

You can do something similar for your case.
To get an idea of what you should write, do the same set of events you mentioned and analyze them using [getevent](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/getevent.html).